# What is the difference between allprojects and subprojects

Tags: gradle

On a multi-project gradle build, can someone tell me what exactly is the difference between the "allprojects" section and the "subprojects" one?  Just the parent directory?  Does anyone use both?  If so, do you have general rules that determines what typically is put in each one?

Related question: what is the difference between the two syntaxes (really for allprojects AND subprojects):

```
subprojects {  ...
}
```

and

```
configure(subprojects) { ...
}
```

When would you one over the other?

Comment: For future reference: I had to add `apply plugin: 'dokka'` inside root build.gradle for it to register the `dokkaHtmlMultiModule` tasks in the parent project. Just applying the plugin in subprojects didn't add this task to the parent (obviously). Adding the `apply` works both directly in root build.gradle, or nested in `allprojects`, because `allprojects` covers everything. But I could also add it to the root, and then in `subprojects` apply it only to chosen sub projects. Or I could add it to `build.gradle` in chosen modules. Or using `project(":subproj") {}`. Very flexible.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

In a multi-project gradle build, you have a rootProject and the subprojects. The combination of both is allprojects.  The rootProject is where the build is starting from. A common pattern is a rootProject has no code and the subprojects are java projects. In which case, you apply the java plugin to only the subprojects:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

This would be equivalent to a maven aggregate pom project that just builds the sub-modules.

Concerning the two syntaxes, they do the exact same thing. The first one just looks better.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your answer, and why one would want "rootProject has no code"?

Comment: It can have code but *most of the time* it is just for combining all sub projects under a single root project.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that applying `java` plugin enables you to use plugin related blocks e.g. `dependencies {}` inside scope of `subprojects { dependencies { ... } }`.

Answer (score 57):

Adding to Ryan's answer, the `configure` method becomes important when you want to configure custom subsets of objects. For example `configure([project(":foo"), project(":bar")]) { ... }` or `configure(tasks.matching { it.name.contains("foo") }) { ... }`.

When to use `allprojects` vs. `subprojects` depends on the circumstances. Often you'll use both. For example, code related plugins like the Java plugin are typically applied to `subprojects`, because in many builds the root project doesn't contain any code. The Eclipse and IDEA plugins, on the other hand, are typically applied to `allprojects`. If in doubt, look at examples and other builds and/or experiment. The general goal is to avoid irrelevant configuration. In that sense, `subprojects` is better than `allprojects` as long as it gives the expected results.

Comment: what if some of my sub projects depends on protocol buffers? should I apply proto-gradle-plugin across all ? or sub or only to those few projects in sub?

Comment: @user1870400 If i understand the answer correctly you should be able to use `configure` with a matching pattern to filter those subprojects that need a specific plugin.