# Gradle tests from testng selenium

Tags: selenium, gradle, testng

I got a gradle script that should run the testng xml files from command line. But whenever I try to run is with grald test I get the following output. With no test run even no browser opened

```
C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Projects\automation>gradle test
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

My gradle script is the following

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

group = 'automation'
version = '1.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = ""

repositories {

     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version:'2.52.0'
    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version:'1.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity', version:'1.7'
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version:'4.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'3.8.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version:'6.9.4'
}
test{
    useTestNG{

    include '/src/test/resources/BasicTestXML/**'}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution how to run them and choose which to run

```
test{

    useTestNG() {
        suites "src/test/resources/BasicTestXML/LoginTest.xml"
    }
}
```

In this way you can choose which xml file it will run. If you want an extra to run just add an extra suites line.

Answer (score 0):

`include` is used to include (or not) test classes: 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

What you are looking for is 
[`suites`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/testng/TestNGOptions.html#suites(java.lang.String...)).
See an example from [the TestNG build file](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/build.gradle#L153).

Comment: test{
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/resources/BasicTestXML/LoginTesten.xml'
    }
}

Comment: I added this to the build file but it gives the same output as the other one

Comment: What is the debug output of gradle saying?

Comment: And how can I run that because I used gradle test -Dtest.single=LoginTesten -Dtest.debug but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm not a gradle expert but maybe "gradle test -i" will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150119/gradle-compiles-but-does-not-run-testng-tests?rq=1